# Why does “a pesar de” signify “in spite of”?

Tags: etimología

In Spanish and Portuguese, *a pesar de* means *in (de)spite of*. But in both languages, *pesar* has never meant *spite* – see quotation below on the etymology of *spite*.  [*pesar*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pesar#Spanish) hails

> From [Old Spanish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Spanish) *[pesar](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pesar#Old_Spanish)*, from [Vulgar Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulgar_Latin) **pēsāre*, from [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin) *[pēnsāre](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pensare#Latin)*,  present active indicative of *[pēnsō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/penso#Latin)*.

How does *a pesar de* yield the meaning *in spite of*?

> #### spite [13]

> *Spite* was adapted from Old French
> *despit* ‘scorn, ill will’, which was also borrowed
> intact as *despite* [13]. This came from Latin
> *dēspectus*, the past participle of *dēspicere* ‘look
> down on’ (source of English despise [13]),
> which was a compound verb formed from the
> prefix d*ē-* ‘down’ and *specere* ‘look’ (source of
> English *spectacle, spy*, etc). The use of *in spite of*
> and *despite* for ‘notwithstanding’ goes back **via
> an intermediate ‘in defiance of’ to an original ‘in
> contempt of’**.

*Word Origins* (2005 2e) by John Ayto. p 473 Left column.

Comment: I would also suspect a link with **"el pésame,"** which in English would be "to feel **sorry** for." Whereas "to be sorry for" would be translated in neighbouring Dutch as "**spijt** hebben om," with "spijt" ultimately being derived from the Latin **"despicere."** Well, at least, here you have an insight into my personal mind map.

Answer (score 10):

According to [this paper](http://www.javierelvira.es/pesares.pdf) (see pages 8 to 11), "pesar" in the lexicalized expression "a pesar de" is related to the meaning of "pesar" as "regret" or "sorrow" and was initially used only for people ("a pesar de alguien": to the regret of somebody):

> (13) Ellos las han dexadas a pesar de nós” (Cid) (Ellos las han abandonado para nuestro
> pesar: They have abandoned them to our regret)

Gradually, the expression started to be used with any kind of grammatical object, for example:

- Ellos las han abandonado a pesar de nuestra súplica (they have abandoned them in spite of our request).

I think some kind of parallel can be drawn with the meaning of the noun "spite" meaning "anger". "In spite of" would then stem from an expression meaning that something caused somebody's anger, something similar to "showing contempt or scorn for" (She married him in spite of me) and gradually evolved to refer to animate and inanimate objects (She married him in spite of my warning).

[image: despite]

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to read it when I get home. But how did *pesar* semantically shift to signify "regret" or "sorrow"?

Comment: Please see the definition of the noun "pesar" (entry 2 at the bottom) here: https://dle.rae.es/pesar

Answer (score 1):

Pesar also means "to weigh" in Spanish, so it can also be viewed as signifying an occurrence in spite of the burden that something else caused, which could have impeded it.